# Optimized SQL for timetable

Tags: mysql, sql, database, storage

I want to create a SQL table in my database that can hold a school timetable but every way i tried to proceed with it it was no optimal and over the course of 1-2 changes to the timetable the database table got a bit too big.

It goes a bit like this:

```
         Mo   Tu   Wed   Thu   Fri
 07:00
 08:00
 09:00
 10:00
 11:00
 12:00
 13:00
 14:00
 15:00
 16:00
```

This is the basic layout of the timetable and in the table the first 2 columns are timetableid and classid. My first approach was to have columns for each day with the classes in one column but that was a bit buggy, my next approach was to get the columns like this mo_7, mo_8, mo_9 etc. until i reach fri_16 but that took up too much space.

So my question is, what is the most optimal way to save a timetable in a database, in what table layout.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `id, timestamp, name_of_event` is all you need. Stop thinking of your data in terms of how it gets presented to the user - humans love their spreadsheet-type displays, but computers don't work in those terms.

Comment: I'm not certain what you are trying to accomplish with this.  Are you just trying to store what day of the week, what time, and what class are associated together?

Comment: Well, i am tying to store the ID of the timetable, Id of the class that has that timetable and then day of the week the course and the hour the course is at. So preferably all in one row.

Comment: If you store the timestamp you can extract the day and hour in the application level. No need to store those separately.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't your database, it's because you're trying to use it like a spreadsheet.

You need to backtrack a little - store a table of classes, along with the various attributes. If each class has only one session, then add 'time' as an attribute. If there's multiple sessions, your probably then need to separate out the schedule into a seperate table.

E.g.:

Table 'classes':

- ClassID.
- description
- teacher
- other stuff.

Table 'sessions':

- session ID
- ClassID
- start_time
- end_time
- day
- location

And then you'd use a select to query e.g.

```
SELECT classID, start_time, day, location 
FROM sessions 
WHERE day like "Monday" 
ORDER BY start_time
```

Which'd give you your list for Monday. To extend it, you might add a join with the 'classes' table.

```
SELECT classes.description, classes.teacher, sessions.start_time, sessions.day, sessions.location
FROM sessions, classes
JOIN ON classes.ClassID = sessions.ClassID
WHERE day LIKE 'Monday'
ORDER BY sessions.start_time
```

Something like that anyway (apologies if the syntax is a bit off, I'll check/amend if I can).

But the point is - let the database store the *actual data* and use the queries to transform it into a layout that you like. That way you don't need to rewrite your database each time you want to change something minor.